# linq to entity - include with lambda expression

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, lambda

I have a lite problem i don't really know how to fix. In my example below i would like to select a list of ProductCategories with ProductItems that are active.

```
public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> ListProductCategories()
        {
            return _entities.ProductCategorySet.Include("ProductItems").Where(x => x.ProductItems.Active == true).ToList();               
        }
```

The problem is that i can't access productItem property Active in my lambda expression, what is the problem? Do I think totaly wrong when im trying to write a linq query like the one above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There could be more than one item. You probably want to select the categories where **all** items are active:

```
return _entities.ProductCategorySet
                .Include("ProductItems")
                .Where(x => x.ProductItems.All(item => item.Active))
                .ToList();
```

Comment: the solution didn't really solve the problem. Your solution only return productcategories with any productitems. It dosn't matter if they are active or not.

What i want to return is all productcategories and productitems only where productitems is active == true.